# Text boxes are not filling when the Form Loads, Windows Form Application

Tags: c#

I am doing following on form Load,

1. I am searching for a file and if file not exist then
2. Fill in some textboxes on the form.
3. Create a file name, `data.txt`
4. Take data from text boxes and write it in the file.

The problem is that the textboxes are not filling with text. I am running the program every time with deleting the file, so that the 1st condition gets true. But still the textboxes on the form remains empty. I am using Visual Studio 2012.

I am using following code under, `InitializeComponent();`

```
string folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);

// Combining the base folder with specific folder....
     string path= Path.Combine(folder, "CRM");

// Checking if folder exists and if not, create it
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

    if (!File.Exists(path + "\\data.txt"))
    {
        txtBoxLimitPerMinute.Text = "300";
        txtBoxSenderName.Text = "Sender Name";
        txtBoxToEmail.Text = "some email id";
        txtBoxSMTPHost.Text = "host name";

        string data = txtBoxSenderName.Text + "," + txtBoxSubject.Text + "," + txtBoxToEmail.Text + "," + txtBox_HtmlPath.Text + "," + txtBoxUnsubscribe.Text + "," + txtBoxSMTPHost.Text + ";

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path+ "\\data.txt", FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                w.WriteLine(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the value of `path`?

Comment: I updated my questing with value of "path" in it.

Comment: There is no reason apparent for this code to not work. I would start the debugger, put a breakpoint on the initial line and follow step by step to see what really happens here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have written your code under `IntializeComponent()` method then make sure after code which you written, Textbox values are not assigned back to string.empty value. (i.e Textbox values are not being overwrite like as below)

E.g.

```
this.txtBoxLimitPerMinute.Text = String.Empty;
```

And Also write your code after `this.Controls.Add(this.txtBoxLimitPerMinute);` because when controls add to form it will reset to default value. So, you need to write your code after all controls have added in forms or four textboxs added in form.

But I suggest to write code after `IntializeComponent()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to write you code after **InitializeComponent()**

because **InitializeComponent()** method creates the object of your text boxes and other controls so I will suggest you to perform any operation on controls after their creation.

Comment: The OP already stated "I am using following code under, InitializeComponent();"

Comment: yes this is what I am saying OP said he is using the code under InitializeComponent() that is wrong..  If an OP says I am adding 1 and 1 and expecting result 3. then it doesn't mean we have to invent something new to prove his statement is correct. If OP doing some mistake we can guide him what is correct way to do this.. this is what i have done..!!

Comment: IF the code is being added under InitializeComponent() then InitializeComponent() is being called first then all the other code is then executed. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: no its not like that.. compiler is not enough intelligent to decide **because this statement accessing the textbox so let it put on hold and first create the text box then resume it..** thats why I am saying.. in constructor of Form first call the InitializeComponent() then do whatever you want.. you can do any task before initialization but those statement are not suppose to access any control which you are going to create in InitializeComponent() method.

Comment: Yes, I do know that, thanks. I think the OP knows this aswell, which is why the code is run after `InitializeComponent()`. But don't worry too much.

Answer (score 0):

Write your code after InitializeComponent()

then use this.txtBoxLimitPerMinute.Text = "300";